# Function not using passed values

Tags: c++, function, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I have this program which is not working as expected: https://pastebin.com/7CnUQH95

```
void percent::setP1Votes(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h, int i, int j) {
    std::cout<< "\n" << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << " " << e << " " << f << " " << h << " " << i << " " << j;
    p1votes = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j;
}

report2.setP1Votes(person0.getPrecint1(), person1.getPrecint1(),
                   person2.getPrecint1(), person3.getPrecint1(),
                   person4.getPrecint1(), person5.getPrecint1(),
                   person6.getPrecint1(), person7.getPrecint1(),
                   person8.getPrecint1(), person9.getPrecint1());
```

The above line is being fed the following values for personX.getPrecint1():

```
120 100 0 250 300 87 284 0 0 0
```

That is what I expect to be output to the console when the above line runs. Instead, the program outputs:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: And what happens if, outside that function, you do `std::cout << person0.GetPricint1()` ?

Comment: Odd. I have all the person objects stored in a vector called people. people[0].getPrecint1() returns 120, whereas person0.getPrecint1() returns 0.

Comment: This is what a debugger is for. You need to learn how to use your debugger.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the values passed to `report2.setP1Votes()` are actually zeros. Usually such behavior means that unexpected object copy occurs somewhere.

The problem is in vector initialisation. This call puts copies of persons in array, not actual objects:

```
std::vector<person> people = { person0, person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6, person7, person8, person9 };
```

Since you call `setData()` on array values only, the actual `person0, person1, person2`, ... get never reinitialized and remain the same value since their construction.

The solution would be to use the array of pointers:

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<person> > people;
```

Comment: An alternative solution would be to remove the `personN` variables altogether. Initialize the vector as `people(10)` and replace all `personN` references with `people[N]`.